# Como utilizar os códigos do plunker em minhas aplicações?

Tags: angularjs

Sou profissional Oracle há 12 anos e estou iniciando no desenvolvimento web com AngularJS.

Procurei pela internet por "login screen angularJs" e cheguei ao plunker com seu modelo: http://embed.plnkr.co/tg25kr/?show=preview

Obviamente, me empolguei e baixei o código fonte e para a minha decepção, não funcionou em meus browsers.

A pergunta é: Por quê?! Se o código é o mesmo que aparece no plunker, o que está faltando para que ele funcione?

Comment: Tira uma dúvida, os códigos copiados dos scripts estão com `http://`?

Comment: Precisamos de um pouco mais de informação, como por exemplo: Um erro é apresentado? Se sim, qual erro? Quais são os "sintomas" apresentados quando você executa o código?

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa de um servidor para rodar o AngularJS.

Uma opção muito simples é o NodeJS, através do seu módulo [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server).

#### Instalação:

Para instalar globalmente digite: `npm install -g http-server`.

#### Execução:

Entre no diretório do projeto e rode com `http-server -o`.

O parâmetro `-o` abre o navegador na página principal do projeto.